# Remove files from all locations - what happens when?

Tags: delete, sharepoint-library

So my collegue managed to delete a whole SharePoint library (+180K files) via Windows Explorer. In the online view these files are already deleted but he get's a notification via his OneDrive client like this:
[image]

I'm now unsure what to do. What exactly happens when he clicks **remove** or **restore**.

**Remove** in my opinion deletes the local copies of the online files.
Will **Restore files** bring back the online files? From the online recycle bin or the local copies?